# How to merge Spreadsheets and Set their tab order in the new document

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-drive-api

I am using the below code to combine spreadsheets in a folder on Gdrive. I am trying to figure out how to combine the sheets but know what order they are in. For instance, if I have 4 files in a folder named SS1, SS2, SS3, SS4. How do i make sure that the 4 tabs in the unified sheet will be SS1, SS2, SS3, SS4 and not some random order like my code currently does now. For instance, my code might spit out an order like SS2, SS1, SS4, SS3.

```js
function mergeSheets() {

  /* Retrieve the desired folder */
  var myFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(SOURCE).next();

  /* Get all spreadsheets that resided on that folder */
  var spreadSheets = myFolder.getFilesByType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");

  /* Create the new spreadsheet that you store other sheets */  
  var newSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Merged Sheets");

  /* Iterate over the spreadsheets over the folder */
  while(spreadSheets.hasNext()) {

    var sheet = spreadSheets.next();

    /* Open the spreadsheet */
    var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(sheet.getId());

    /* Get all its sheets */
    for(var y in spreadSheet.getSheets()) {

      /* Copy the sheet to the new merged Spread Sheet */
      spreadSheet.getSheets()[y].copyTo(newSpreadSheet); 
    }
  }      
}
```

Comment: Please don't add the stack snippet to Google Apps Script code. It's only for JavaScript/HTML/CSS that is executable by the Stack Fiddle.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you could do is to store the result of the extracted files (your while loop) in an array, then sort the array and finally append the sheet that are sorted in the array (as the value of an array are ordered).

here your code re vamped with what I had in mind (didn't tested it so there may be some bug)

```
function mergeSheets() {

  /* Retrieve the desired folder */
  var myFolder = DriveApp.getFoldersByName(SOURCE).next();

  /* Get all spreadsheets that resided on that folder */
  var spreadSheets = myFolder.getFilesByType("application/vnd.google-apps.spreadsheet");

  /* Create the new spreadsheet that you store other sheets */  
  var newSpreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.create("Merged Sheets");

  /* Iterate over the spreadsheets over the folder */
  var spreadsheetsList = [];
  while(spreadSheets.hasNext()) {

    var sheet = spreadSheets.next();
    spreadsheetsList.push([sheet.getName(),sheet.getId()]);
  }
  spreadsheetsList.sort(function(a,b){return a[0].localCompare(b[0])});
  for(var i =0; i< spreadsheetsList.length; i++){
    /* Open the spreadsheet */
    var spreadSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetsList[i][1]);

    /* Get all its sheets */
    for(var y in spreadSheet.getSheets()) {

      /* Copy the sheet to the new merged Spread Sheet */
      spreadSheet.getSheets()[y].copyTo(newSpreadSheet); 
    }
  }      
}
```